# ASP.NET не отрабатывает javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

Здравствуйте. Есть проект ASP.NET При его запуске вылетает вот такая вот ошибка на javascript коде. Вот код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            Ext.onReady(
                  function () {
                      var task = {
                          run: function () { Ext.Ajax.request({ url: '/Handlers/SessionLifeStub.ashx' }); },
                          interval: 300000
                      }
                      var runner = new Ext.util.TaskRunner();
                      runner.start(task);
                  }
              );
        </scr
```

> 0x800a1391 - Ошибка выполнения JavaScript: "Ext" не определено

Я не могу понять что не хватает проекту. Может что то нужно докачать или в чём дело?

Comment: Судя по всему, у Вас объект Ext не объявлен, или объявлен после выполнения данного скрипта. Нужно или поменять порядок скриптов, чтобы в одном скрипте Ext был объявлен, а после него шло уже выполнение этого скрипта

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin на сколько я понял дело в EXT.NET не пойму как его поставить только что бы всё заработало.

Comment: Он должен быть объявлен до выполнения этого скрипта, попробуйте переместить этот скрипт в самый низ тега body, возможно это решит вашу проблему

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin, у меня для проекта не докачен EXT.NET при чём тут сам скрипт.

Comment: Возможно, Ext.Net поставлен как Nuget-пакет и вам нужно восстановить пакеты?

Comment: @AK возможно, через nuget попробовал поставить EXT.NET не помогло, может что то не так сделал, поэтому собственно говоря и задал вопрос, не могу понять в чём проблема и как решить.

Comment: Я не знаю, как помочь человеку, который говорит "я может что-то не так сделал" но не рассказывает, что он конкретно сделал. Предлагаю вам добавить информацию в вопрос о том, что и как вы делали и что не получалось, иначе попытки помочь вам будут мало отличаться от попыток толпы экстрасенсов угадать, в чём была проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, `Ext` - это глобальная переменная, которая используется фреймворкм `Ext Js`, разрабатываемый компанией [Sencha](https://www.sencha.com/)

Во-вторых, попробуйте подключить `Ext.NET` библиотеку посредством `Nuget`. Пример работы с [хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/post/145757/).

Официальная страница [Ext.NET](http://ext.net/)

[Примеры решений](http://examples.ext.net/) с использованием Ext.NET

Если для вас это сложно, попробуйте простой путь, подключите Js-библиотеку в `header`'e веб страницы:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
```